# Comment flag declined, all comments now deleted - what happened?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags

I have flagged two comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517471/c-codeblocks-disassembly-way-too-much-code), one as *rude or offensive* and the other as *not constructive*. Both flags have been declined, but apparently all the comments have now been deleted. I am not aware of a way to see deleted comments, so I must quote them from memory. The first one went like

> WTF were you smoking that made you think asking this was a good idea?

Funnily enough I do see tons of questions where I wonder about that myself, but in this case I don't see anything wrong with the question. The second comment by another person was just some agreeing reply to the first one.

The question is now closed due to being `too broad` which in my opinion is also wrong, especially since it has an upvoted accepted answer by a high-rep user clearly demonstrating that it was possible to answer "in a few paragraphs". By the way, I have also provided a quick answer in a comment before everybody else. (I didn't have time to write an elaborate answer that's why I used a comment.) This comment also got deleted along with the others.

I have the following questions:

1. Why were my flags declined?
2. Why were the comments deleted then?
3. Is there a way to see deleted comments? Does it need a certain rep maybe?
4. Would it make sense to vote for reopen if I don't agree with the closing, even though it has a good answer that is unlikely to be surpassed?
5. Bonus question: Should I have asked questions #3-5 in separate posts? :)

Update: Courtesy of @George Stocker, the exact comment was:

> WTF are you posting this for? Share whatever is is you're smoking
>   that made you think posting this was a good idea.

Comment: Answer to #3 No, you can't see deleted comments. Only mods and SE employees can.

Comment: @bluefeet technically then, the answer is yes, if you become a mod or an SE employee :P

Comment: Given the question _"Are you freakin' kiddin' me???"_, the WTF comment is actually pretty spot on ;) (or at least pretty much in line with the question)

Comment: Ah, yet another edition of these.... But at least the moderator seems to regret it in here (kudos!), unlike some other mods. I will not indicate names.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Why were my flags declined?

As the moderator who declined the flags, I am the one who can answer this question. Or; I would be, if I had any clue whatsoever why I may have declined those flags! Clearly, the comments in question needed to be deleted, and the ones flagged needed to be deleted *for the reason they were flagged*.

So, I goofed there, definitely.

And, apparently realized my mistake very quickly thereafter, and wiped all the junk.

Apologies for the mixed signal I sent there. The flags were wholly correct!

Comment: Kudos for admitting that.

Answer (score 20):

> 1. Why were my flags declined?

I'm not sure why they were declined. I wasn't the mod who processed them, it's entirely possible that the mod didn't agree that the "WTF" comment was rude or offensive so they declined the flag. I probably would have marked them as helpful and deleted them.

> 2. Why were the comments deleted then?

While the mod may not have agreed with your flags on the comments, they might have felt that overall the comments were too chatty, etc. so that is why they deleted all of them.

> 3. Is there a way to see deleted comments? Does it need a certain rep maybe?

Unless you are a mod or a SE employee you can't see deleted comments.

> 4. Would it make sense to vote for reopen if I don't agree with the closing, even though it has a good answer that is unlikely to be surpassed?

If you think that the question is on-topic or can be edited to be on-topic, then sure you can vote to reopen it. But just because a question has a good answer doesn't necessarily make the question on-topic.  There are a lot of good answers to questions that are closed for being off-topic.

> 5. Bonus question: Should I have asked questions #3-5 in separate posts? :)

Possibly, because now I feel like this answer is sort of long-winded. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you can see the comments, and it is not against policy, could you please edit them into my question? As for #4 I am pretty confident it's on topic, I just wonder if it makes sense to reopen given it already has a good answer, so what's the point?

Comment: The comment the OP refers to actually says: `"WTF are you posting this for? Share whatever is is you're smoking that made you think posting this was a good idea. "` instead of what they posted.

Comment: @Jester if it's reopened, then it's entirely possible that we could get more good answers and that's what SE is all about. Getting good answers to good questions, so if you think it is on-topic or can be edited into something on-topic, then edit it and vote to reopen.